# Android upload file to server networkonmainexception

Tags: php, android

I am doing an android application to upload audio files to my web folder. However, I'm getting a NetworkOnMainException.

**Here's what I've tried so far:**

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO onClick
        openGalleryAudio();
}

   public void openGalleryAudio(){

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("audio/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Audio "), SELECT_AUDIO);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == SELECT_AUDIO)
        {
            System.out.println("SELECT_AUDIO");
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("SELECT_AUDIO Path : " + selectedPath);

                     doFileUpload();    
        }


    }
}

 public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
 }

 private void doFileUpload(){
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null;
        String lineEnd = "rn";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
        String responseFromServer = "";
        String urlString = "http://mlssabio.x10.mx/strings-of-beads/webservice/uploadsong.php";
        try
        {
         //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(selectedPath) );
         // open a URL connection to the Servlet
         URL url = new URL(urlString);
         // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
         conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         // Allow Inputs
         conn.setDoInput(true);
         // Allow Outputs
         conn.setDoOutput(true);
         // Don't use a cached copy.
         conn.setUseCaches(false);
         // Use a post method.
         conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
         dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

         dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name='uploaded_file';filename='"
                 + selectedPath + "'" + lineEnd);

         //dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ selectedPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
         // create a buffer of maximum size
         bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
         bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
         buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
         // read file and write it into form...
         bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
         while (bytesRead > 0)
         {
          dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
          bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
          bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
          bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
         }
         // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
         dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
         // close streams
         Log.e("Debug","File is written");
         fileInputStream.close();
         dos.flush();
         dos.close();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException ex)
        {
             Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
             Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
        //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
        try {
              inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
              String str;

              while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
              {
                   Log.e("Debug","Server Response "+str);
              }
              inStream.close();

        }
        catch (IOException ioex){
             Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
        }
 }
```

It gives me NetworkOnMainException..

**I tried changing to:**

```
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                Log.d("Test", "uploading started.....");
                            }
                        });                      

                     doFileUpload();

                }
              }).start();
```

But now it gives me OutOfMemory error

**Full logcat error here:**

```
 12-29 04:58:00.284: E/AndroidRuntime(3959): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-108
 12-29 04:58:00.284: E/AndroidRuntime(3959): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
 12-29 04:58:00.284: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:91)
 12-29 04:58:00.284: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:201)
 12-29 04:58:00.284: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):    at libcore.net.http.RetryableOutputStream.write(RetryableOutputStream.java:61)
 12-29 04:58:00.284: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:98)
 12-29 04:58:00.284: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):    at com.thesis.string.of.beads.AddSong.doFileUpload(AddSong.java:188)
 12-29 04:58:00.284: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):    at com.thesis.string.of.beads.AddSong.access$0(AddSong.java:142)
 12-29 04:58:00.284: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):    at com.thesis.string.of.beads.AddSong$1.run(AddSong.java:124)
 12-29 04:58:00.284: E/AndroidRuntime(3959):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

**Line 188:**

```
              dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
```

I don't know what's wrong or missing in this code your help will truly be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What did you learn when you searched StackOverflow or Google for the hundreds of questions and answers related to `NetworkOnMainThreadException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Its because you're doing network operation on** `Main UI thread`

if you're using threads to do network operations
then you can use this code snippet

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
        new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

in your `OnCreate()`

But its wrong practice to use above said operation, instead you should use `AsyncTask` class provided by android to handle properly network operation `without blocking UI thread`.

you can learn more by visiting this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#usage)

or can use the below code

```
private class UploadFiles extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
     protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
         //THIS METHOD WILL BE CALLED AFTER ONPREEXECUTE
         //YOUR NETWORK OPERATION HERE
         return null;
     }

     protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();
         //THIS METHOD WILL BE CALLED FIRST
         //DO OPERATION LIKE SHOWING PROGRESS DIALOG PRIOR TO BEGIN NETWORK OPERATION
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         super.onPostExecute();
         //TNIS METHOD WILL BE CALLED AT LAST AFTER DOINBACKGROUND
         //DO OPERATION LIKE UPDATING UI HERE
     }
 }
```

and you can simple call this class by writing

```
 new UploadFiles ().execute(new String[]{//YOUR LINK});
```

Comment: thanks but can you give me some sample implementations of asynctask in the above code that I used?

Comment: thank you! It now works but I'm still getting the OutOfMemoryError

Comment: @Dunkey `OUTOFMEMORY` is different issue, you stated the problem of `networkOnUiThread` that's what i provided you solution with, you should accept the answer if its helpful to you

Comment: Okay I accepted your answer, can you please help me figure out what's wrong with my second problem? here's the link to my new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825718/android-outofmemoryerror-when-sending-audio-file-to-server